# Missing mod_deflate.so?

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd, mod-deflate

I'm trying to build apache with mod_deflate enabled. When restarting apache I'm presented with the following error:

`httpd: Syntax error on line 36 of /usr/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load /usr/local/apache/modules/mod_deflate.so into server: /usr/local/apache/modules/mod_deflate.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

How can I get mod_deflate.so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you compiled Apache yourself, but you didn't choose to use the mod_deflate module. You'll need to recompile it, and this time [enable mod_deflate](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/configure.html).

```
./configure --enable-deflate ...the rest of your options...
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess when you compiled apache you forgot to include mod_deflate. So if you decide to recompile everything again just add `--enable-deflate`.

Another option is compile the module as a dynamic shared object (DSO) in the current apache. Have a look at this [blog post](http://streetsmartingit.blogspot.com.au/2007/11/how-to-compileinstall-moddeflate-into.html).